# How to can I print an array transferred from javascript to php from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, post

I am trying to transfer a javascript array to a php array and I used the following code in my php file to do so:

```
    var rowArr=[];
    var currow=$(this.closest('tr'));
    var col1=currow.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    rowArr.push(col1);
    var col2=currow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    rowArr.push(col2);
    var col3=currow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    rowArr.push(col3);
    var myJSONText = JSON.stringify( rowArr );

   $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "jsonRecieve.php", 
        data: { emps : myJSONText}, 
        success: function() { 
        alert("Success"); 
    } 
 });
```

so when I run this code, I get the success alert but I am not seeing any of the array elements being printed out. I am also not getting any error messages.Here is my **jsonRecieve.php**:

```
<?php
   $rowAr=$_POST['emps'];
   print_r($rowAr);
?>
```

is there a way to verify that it has been transferred? I don't believe it has but if it hasn't can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to decode the json string with `json_decode()` to get your `emps` value on the server side and to alert the server response need to send something from the server. Let's debug this way-

**ON JS**

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "jsonRecieve.php", 
        data: { emps : myJSONText}, 
        success: function(data) {     
        alert(data);  // alert your data to see that returns from server
    }
```

**ON PHP**

```
<?php
   $rowAr=$_POST['emps'];
   $array = json_decode($rowAr,1); // 2nd params 1 means decode as an array
   print_r($array);
   die('response from the server');
?>
```

Comment: so I got it to print through your edits, thank you. But when it does that does it mean that the array is now saved under $_POST['emps']? because I want to fill in a forms input boxes with the arrays information in php and when I try to initialize an array in my php file with $_POST['emps'] it says that it is an undefined index

Comment: and also in the ajax function under url, do you have to send it to a separate php file or are you able to send it in the same file?

Comment: Yes you can get the form input values with serializeArray before passing them to your php file, have a look here https://gomakethings.com/getting-an-array-of-form-data-with-vanilla-js/ also the same file can do your job. No need to use another php file

Comment: no, I mean id like to use the javascript array that has been converted into php to be used as placeholders for the form. How will I do that?